# Stratification and randomization in excel

Tags: excel

I am working on a medicine risk tool in excel.I am trying to make a stratification of my data by medicine risk levels and a randomization of cities by risk levels. I want the randomization to be proportional when it chooses the cities by risk level.

```
Total.City.Region Risk Score    Total.City.Regionl.Risk.Desc    City.Scaled
4.43                                  1. Extremely Low Risk        0.129
443.32                                2. Very Low Risk             0.164
44.33                                 1. Extremely Low Risk        0.132
110.83                                2. Very Low Risk             0.137
221.66                                2. Very Low Risk             0.146
288.16                                2. Very Low Risk             0.151
376.82                                2. Very Low Risk             0.158
4.43                                  1. Extremely Low Risk        0.129
44.33                                 1. Extremely Low Risk        0.132
110.83                                2. Very Low Risk             0.137
```

This a part of my data. So each city has total city risk score and risk levels are based on the risk score. Then I scaled the scores to normalize it. Now I want to create a formula that stratifies my data  by risk levels. (Extremely low risk, very low risk and low risk) and then pick random cities (fox ex 5 cities in total) from each level (first from extremely low risk then very low risk and then low risk) but I want this to be in a proportional way.

Any help or suggestion on how I can do this will be very helpful

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like a use-case for VBA than simple spreadsheet formulas. A pivot table could help with the stratification part.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your suggestion. I am trying to do the stratification and randomization automatically everytime someone enters new data in the sheet but I can't find a way to do this in excel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, and provided you're using Office 365, you can use the SWITCH statement to evaluate the City.Scaled column and return the textual risk description.  An example to work from:

```
=SWITCH(C2,IF(VALUE(C2) < 0.135,C2,""),"ExLow","low")

0.129   ExLow
0.164   low
0.132   ExLow
0.137   low
0.146   low
0.151   low
0.158   low
0.129   ExLow
0.132   ExLow
0.137   low
```

The first term in the above switch formula contain an expression to match against, the next is a comparison value, then a return value if it matches, followed by a default.  you can repeat the 2nd and 3rd for up to 126 match/return pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on the test data and it seemed to work. For the purposes of this example, let's assume the Total City Risk Score is in Column A, the Risk Description is in Column B, and the Scaled Score is in Column C:

1. Sort on column B
2. Starting in D2, we are going to do the following formula: `=IF(B2<>B3,ROW(B2),"")`. Drag this down to the bottom. Essentially we are trying to find the rows that mark the end of each block of Risk Descriptions.
3. Starting G2, just make a list from 1,2....until the number of categories you have. I only see three in the sample data so 1,2,3 may be all you need
4. In H1, let's create a header called "Start". This will record where blocks of Risk Descriptions begin. We'll come back here in a bit.
5. In I1, create a header called "End". This will record where a blocks of Risk Descriptions end. In I2, we will use the following formula: `=LARGE(D:D,3-G2+1)`. Again, the `3` represents the number of Risk Descriptions. Drag down to the end of this mini table we are making.
6. Hop back to H2. Set H2 equal to 1. H3 should be: `=I2-1`. Drag this down.
7. In J1, create a header called "Size" to record the number of entries in each block of Risk Descriptions. In J2, use the formula: `=I2-H2+1` (Ending row - Beginning Row + 1). Drag this down.
8. Almost done! Now in K1, create a header called "Random". In K2 put the following formula: `=H2+RANDBETWEEN(0,J2-1)`. Drag down. Essentially, we want to create a random number that is between 0 and 1 less than the size of the block. Then we add that to the first row in the block. This gives us a random row within the block of Risk Descriptions for each Risk Description.
9. In L1, create a header called "Value". In L2, use the formula: `=INDIRECT("C"&K2)`. Drag down. This will return the Scaled Score for the random row chosen. Change C to A or B if you want other data.

Now in column L, you have 1 random entry from each block. If you want 5 from each, you can refresh 5 times.

Note: This is not control for a single entry being chosen twice.

Comment: Hi Ankur, thank you for your help. I was having issues with the formula in D2, it is showing NAME. It might be a typing error?. Is there any way to do the srtaification and randomization automatically everytime new data in inserted?

Comment: Hi there - I am so sorry for taking so long to get back! Is this resolved? If not I can look into the D2 issue!